# backbone.js design pattern for a dashboard

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, backbone.js

I'm building a dashboard application with Backbone.js

There is a grid of panes called modules. Each module has its own custom data that it needs to listen to.

each module has both shared responsibilities and separate responsibilities, as in, they all have titles, descriptions, etc, and yet they each have individual datasets.

how should I structure the application to achieve the constant flow of data to these separate modules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When dealing with so many dependencies I would suggest a global pubSub class via

```
var pubsub = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

This way you can share events through

```
pubsub.on('some:channel', function () {
    console.log('channel ', arguments);
});
pubsub.trigger('some:channel', 'Dude...');
```

with multiple modules and structure their response to it.

Comment: this is a good starting point. at what level should I connect those modules to `pubsub`? at the model level? collection? view?

Comment: I usually develop "fat models", i.e. the functionality is bound to every instance. Therefore I can control all model with one behaviour as they are all subscribed to the pubSub class. I usually never use it in the view, but sometimes it can make sense when you want to stop() the whole app. There you would need the pubSub method in the view as well.

Comment: so, what you're saying then, is that it would be good if i developed a base model, and then each subsequent model extends base model. and base model contains a pubsub listener?

Comment: yes. exactly. Also this guide helped me to be better in backbone http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend you using [backbone.marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette)

here is a good [starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410059/suggested-bootstrap-boilerplate-sample-for-backbone-marionette-application) that will help you

i have developed complex dashboard applications using marionette, and the amount of time and effort i saved, was tremendous. naturally marionette incorporate several pub/sub mechanisms that easy your job.